# Audi A3 sometimes starts at the third attempts

Tags: starting, audi

I have a 2006 Audi A3 car w/ 1,6 liter gas engine and an automatic transmission. My trouble is that at times the car will only start at the third attempt. So far my observation is that this seems not be be on cold starts and I was always able to start the car after third attempt at most.

Where should I start looking for the cause/what should I tell the serviceman? Is there any investigation I can perhaps do by myself using OBD II module and a phone? I'm worried that one of those times the car won't start at all, probably when it is least convenient.

As with any malfunctions with unknown cause, I'm worried the service will milk me dry if I let them start replacing things.

Comment: Are you saying that you can crank and crank and crank your car on a single try and it won't start? Then it won't do it again on the second try? But finally on the third try it fires right over? I'm just trying to get a better descriptor of what you are doing when trying to start the car. I have an idea what might be at issue, but without more information, it is all speculation at this point.

Comment: Yes, that's a good description. My vocabulary probably isn't terribly good for describing car issues like this, sorry :-).

Comment: Does it matter if the car is hot or cold when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your starting problem is unknown because the vehicle has not been checked-scanned- for it. A program like Torque Pro will offer you the ability to retrieve fault codes with your smart phone, but a code on its own is not the complete answer. The code should be considered as what the vehicles computer thinks is wrong. In very many instances the component indicated by the fault code is not at fault, but is being affected by another part of the system. Testing of the systems is the art of it. From your description the engine cooling temperature sensor(ECT) is proberly part of the problem. The ECT has a dual circuit. One circuit is used to adjust the fuel when the engine is cold, the second circuit comes into play once the vehicle has started to warm up and reduces the fuel used. This allows a more precise temperature control over the engine heat range. If the second circuit is at fault the engine will be run too rich when warm and cause poor warm starting.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds plausible. Would it be an expensive thing to fix using aftermarket parts? Is this something that if left in this state will lead to further damage to other parts of the car?

Comment: In the Uk the price of an ECT for an A3 is around £25 with sales tax, to the garage trade. Running the engine with an under-reading ECT would cause fuel consumption to increase despite the ECU (engine computer) substituting a value. The ECT is held to the engine by a simple plastic clip and is on the right hand side of the engine. 15 min job.